# what is omitted after 'with' in 'to begin with' & 'get it over with'?

Tags: prepositions

I thought prepositions always have a noun after itself. But these two doesn't.

> To begin/start with,......
>
> let's just get this over with.

why nothing is after the preposition?

Comment: You thought wrong. Winston Churchill is (falsely, I'm sure) reputed to have poked fun at your misconception with [Ending a sentence with a preposition is something up with which I will not put.](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/w/winstonchu122535.html) Which sounds ridiculous to any native speaker (and thereby proves that the "rule" is stupid).

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain what Churchill said more explicitly?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think this is a different matter: OP wants to know the **object** of *with* in these two expressions, which is actually a pretty interesting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To begin/start with*, when not followed by a noun, are parenthetical  expressions that mean *in the first place* or *initially*.

> used to emphasize the first or most significant of a list of reasons, opinions, etc. (OED)

*To get something over with* is a phrasal verb ([Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-sth-over-with)). The 'with' can be analyzed as a particle, not a preposition.

The particles in phrasal verbs do not have to be followed by a noun:

How soon are you going to *get up*?

When did you last *throw up*?

He said he needed to *get out*.